# Interactivity mousewheel only occurring in filled portions of stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a stackpanel set to stretch horizontally and vertically. Inside the stackpanel is a textblock.  When I put an interactivity trigger for mousewheel on the stackpanel, it only triggers when I'm over the textblock.  I assumed that stretching the panel to fill its parent would have fixed this, but it hasn't.  I know the panel is stretched because the background color takes the full area. Is there any way for the trigger to happen within the entire stackpanel? Here's the code:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseWheel">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.PreviousWeekCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
               </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <StackPanel.Style>
               <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Month, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentMonthConverter}}"
                                                     Value="false">
                                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD3D3D3"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Add `Background="transparent"` to your `StackPanel` for hittestvisibility.

Comment: That did it, but I wonder why?  Isn't the background part of the panel and so should pick up the mouse events?  Also, this prevents me from brushing the background as I do with the data trigger in there.

Comment: Nah it's by design so that inherent hittestvisibility is implicit instead of explicit for panels like stackpanel, or scrollviewer, etc. Until you've specified a background, one doesn't technically exist if that makes sense. As for your different background you should be able to change the property with the trigger but a quick workaround would be just add a border or a rectangle or something to change the color of instead but a trigger property change should do it fine...

Comment: Thanks -- works great now.